# defining python function to find combinatrics

Tags: python, string, function

I need to create a python function that finds all possible combinations of letters of set length within a function recursivly. 
For example, using this in the word 'unicorn' to find all combinations of length 3 would return:

['orN', 'crN', 'coN', 'cor', 'irN', 'ioN', 'ior',
                                         'icN', 'icr', 'ico', 'nrN', 'noN', 'nor', 'ncN',
                                         'ncr', 'nco', 'niN', 'nir', 'nio', 'nic', 'urN',
                                         'uoN', 'uor', 'ucN', 'ucr', 'uco', 'uiN', 'uir',
                                         'uio', 'uic', 'unN', 'unr', 'uno', 'unc', 'uni']

I dont even know where to start with this one. Please help me out.

Comment: There is a link here to python string methods. Nobody here will write a solution from scratch. Give it a go, and if you get stuck, post your code so we can help you with it http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-string.html

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
print [''.join(x) for x in itertools.combinations('unicorn', 3)]
```

If you want *exactly* the same output as you asked for:

```
>>> print [''.join(x) for x in itertools.combinations('unicorN', 3)][::-1]
['orN', 'crN', 'coN', 'cor', 'irN', 'ioN', 'ior', 'icN', 'icr', 'ico', 'nrN', 'noN', 'nor', 'ncN', 'ncr', 'nco', 'niN', 'nir', 'nio', 'nic', 'urN', 'uoN', 'uor', 'ucN', 'ucr', 'uco', 'uiN', 'uir', 'uio', 'uic', 'unN', 'unr', 'uno', 'unc', 'uni']
```

Comment: I had deleted my last comment, as I thought about it, realising that you are right :-), in the meantime you commented. Sorry for that!